# Layout is not working on all android devices screen size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have the following layout. I have this layout but it does not fit of all devices.I had the problem that my layouts do not fit on every page and on smaller phones they leave the screen box, although I chose the match parent option for the necessary layouts.Can you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot.

[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TwVi.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThtaU.png)

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMultiple"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDecimalPointClick"
                    android:text="."
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit0"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="clearText"
                    android:text="CLR"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onEqualClick"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what's the point of using constraint layout if you're just going to use linear layouts inside it ?

Comment: Match_parent isn't a magic "make my design fit" button.  Match_parent means it should be exactly as big as the parent.  If your layout doesn't fit in that, it goes beyond the parent and that part  won't be displayed.  Making it work on all screen sizes still requires you to work and create a design that will fit globally.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? I use a combination with RelativeLayout to get shortcode and fix android height and weight issues

> **size 6.0**

[image: size 6.0]

> **size 5.0**

[image: size 5.0]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="Result"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"

                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"

                    android:text="6"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMultiple"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"

                    android:text="*"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onOperatorClick"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDecimalPointClick"
                    android:text="."
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDigit0"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="onDigitClicked"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    android:onClick="clearText"
                    android:text="CLR"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"

                    android:text="+"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"

                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```